# Como eu posso fazer tabelas como essa com html e css?

Tags: html, css3, table

Como fazer tabelas como essa em html ? sou meio noob no front end tentei com bootstrap e não ficou legal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg18t.png

Comment: Você conhece HTML e CSS ?

Comment: conheço, eu to desenvolvendo um sistema em django eu queria uma tabela como essa, mas não to conseguindo fazer

Comment: Segue esse tutorialzinho aqui: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3439/introducao-ao-html-usando-tabelas-em-html.aspx

Ou se preferir assista umas aulas no youtube. Vai te ajudar muito, rapidinho você aprende como faz.